# Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers, version 2.9.4 was not found Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I am getting below error while build application,  I have Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers package is installed.

```
Error   NETSDK1064  Package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers, version 2.9.4 was not found. It might have been deleted since NuGet restore. Otherwise, NuGet restore might have only partially completed, which might have been due to maximum path length restrictions. TA_App  C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.401\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets
```

Comment: Hi @Rajesh Sawant,if you are sure you have installed the package, have you tried to clean the project and rebuild the project(right-click the root project)? If still not working, have you tried to restart the visual studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clear all Nuget packages with this command

```
dotnet nuget locals --clear all
```

after that rebuild your solution will work for you.

Comment: I am seeing this in a docker container build.  I am using net6.0.  This appears to be an SDK version aligned version dependency